# Function unreferenced when hosting on public site

Tags: javascript, reference

So I have this platformer I was working on and it work fine when running locally but when I try to host it online on say itch.io it gives me an error saying the function  runGame is not defined. I will post the .html code where this error is found. The function runGame is found in a seperate game.js file. If I need to post this let me know.

```
<!doctype html>
<script src="code/game.js"></script>
<script src="code/game_levels.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/game.css">

<body>
  <script>
    runGame(GAME_LEVELS, DOMDisplay);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: There's no way we can help you with this, the most likely issue is that the path to the `game_levels.js` file is wrong, but you can find that out by just opening your console (F12)

Comment: @adeneo it was the folder src. My folder "code" was upper case, silly mistake, thanks for the help.